# Cómo ejecutar código luego de que todos los hilos secundarios terminen en Java?

Tags: java, hilos, java-8

Estoy creando un *bechmark* básico en Java, el cual lee el numero de núcleos que tiene la *CPU* de la maquina en donde el programa se ejecuta. Se crean tantos hilos como tenga núcleos el procesador de la maquina.

El caso es que desde el hilo principal del programa, quiero ejecutar un código aparte, pero no se como hacer para que esta parte espere a que todos los hilos secundarios terminen de ejecutarse para que esta ultima parte se ejecute.

Esta es la clase principal, o el hilo principal.

```
public class Main{

    public Main() {
        long numero = 100000;

        ArrayList<Bench> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Bench.getCores(); i++) {
            threads.add(new Bench(numero));
            threads.get(i).start();
        }
        this.calcularTiempos(threads);

    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main m = new Main();
    }

    private void calcularTiempos(ArrayList<Bench> threads) {
        float time = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < threads.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Tiempo del hilo " + i + ": " + threads.get(i).getTime());
            time += threads.get(i).getTime();
        }
        time = time/Bench.getCores();
        System.out.println("Tiempo promedio: " + time);
    }

}
```

El resto de hilos hacen lo mismo que esta en el metodo run:

```
public class Bench implements Runnable{
    private Thread hilo;
    private final long numero;
    private float time;

    public Bench(long numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }


    public BigInteger foo(long n) {
        /****/
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        float inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //while(true){
            for(int i = 0 ; i < numero; i++){
                this.foo(i);
            }
        //}

        this.time = System.currentTimeMillis() - inicio;
    }

    public void start(){
        hilo = new Thread(this, String.valueOf(numero));
        hilo.start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        if(hilo != null){
            hilo.stop();
        }
    }

    public static int getCores(){
        return Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    }

    public float getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(float time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Necesito que la función `calcularTiempos` se ejecute cuando los `n` hilos creados hayan terminado en su ejecución.

Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando `Thread#join()` haces que el `Thread` que llama espere a que termine el `Thread` sobre el que se ha llamado `join()`.

Es decir, el programa se está ejecutando en el `Thread` `t1` , y en ese `Thread` `t1` cramos un nuevo `Thread` `t2`, para que a `t1` espere a que `t2` termine antes de continuar, en `t1` se debe llamar `t2.join()`.

En la pregunta hay varios `Threads` creados desde el `Thread` principal, entonces para que el principal espere a todos ellos, desde el principipal hay que llamar `join()` sobre cada uno de los `Threads` secundarios.

Modifiqué la respuesta anterior por que no corria los `Bench` en paralelo:

Antes de ejecutar el calculo de tiempos, llamamos al join de cada thread para asegurarnos de que el mismo termine antes de seguir adelante:

```
public Main() {
    long numero = 100000;

    ArrayList<Bench> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Bench.getCores(); i++) {
        threads.add(new Bench(numero));
        threads.get(i).start();
    }
    for(Bench thread : threads){
        thread.join(); // Este join es un metod que agregué en Bench
    }
    this.calcularTiempos(threads);

}
```

En Bench agregar:

```
public void join(){
    try{
        hilo.join()
    }catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema es que el join solo me ejecuta un hilo, y se deben ejecutar todos los hilos secundarios excepto el principal. Con esto solo me ejecuta uno de los 4, y no los 4 hilos secundarios a la vez.

Comment: Tenés razón, ahí cambié el código para que llame a los join después de haber iniciado todos los Threads, pero antes de hacer los cálculos de tiempo. Con eso el Thread principal debería esperar a que terminen todos los secundarios antes de continuar.

Comment: Gracias bro, la duda mia es como se debe utilizar el join, me imagino que notifica al hilo en donde se llamo que debe esperar a que todos los n hilos secundarios deben finalizarse para que este tambien siga con el bloque de codigo...

Comment: Ahi te completé la pregunta con lo que estás preguntando. Es casi como lo estás pensando, solo que tenes que llamar join() sobre cada thread que querés esperar a que termine.